# How to find if two strings have common characters in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and trying to find out if two strings share any common characters. I know there should be a simple way to do this without using regex (I'm not opposed to regex) maybe by using `my_str.chars().any()` but I'm not sure how to implement this.

I've done it before in Python by comparing sets.

```
if len(set(candidate) & set(required)) < 1:
```

**EDIT**

```
let result = candidate.chars().any(|c| required.contains(c));
```

So, I was able to get a solution to work using `any`. But since I'm new to rust, I'm not sure if its the best way. Perhaps using `HashSets` would be more efficient? My application is small so efficiency isn't a huge factor. What is the most "rustic" way?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific what you are trying to do, and what your problem is?  Why are you comparing the length to 1 in the Python code?  Have you tried translating the Python code directly to Rust, and did you encounter any problems when doing so?  Currently I don't understand what your specific problem is.

Comment: He wants to find out if strings have characters in common. The python code converts both strings into sets and checks if length of the set intersection is larger than 0.

Comment: @MadWombat I understand what the goal is.  What I don't understand is the specific problems.  The Ptyhon code translates to a Rust implementation in a rather straight-forward way, but the OP seems to have hit some obstacle.  Sure, I could just write the code ([in fact I did](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2c0332c1e65051f72fd4808a95b5d9ad)), but I think I could give a much more useful answer if I understand what the actual problem is.  And regarding the Python code, I was just wondering why it ends with `< 1` instead of `!= 0`.

Comment: (I'd generally write the Python code as simply `if set(s1) & set(s2):` without bothering with `len()`.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks for the code example (you should post it as an answer). I'm new to rust and thought there was probably a simpler way. As for the `< 1`, it should be `!=0` but for some reason I didn't put that when I wrote it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it might be better to use `is_disjoint` instead of building the intersection and then checking it, as it will short-circuit

Comment: @PitaJ When writing Python, I often care more about conciseness and readability than performance, but you are right. :)

Comment: Your solution has time complexity O(_mn_), where _m_ and _n_ are the respective lengths of the two strings.  The solution using sets has an (amortised) complexity of O(_m_ + _n_), so it is asymptotically a lot faster.  For very short strings, it might even be slightly slower, though.

Comment: If the range of possible characters is guaranteed to be small, you can use a bit array to record whether you've seen a character in the first string and then check the bit array for each character in the second array.

Answer (score 2):

You can approach it several ways, here are a couple options:

- build a set of the first string, and check if the second string contains a character in that set [O(n + m)]
- iterate through the first string's characters, and check whether the second string contains any of them [O(n * m)]

I decided to use a `HashSet` but you could use a basic array if you only care about ascii (thus restricted to 256 possibilities).

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn share_char(a: &str, b: &str) -> bool {
    // get which one is shorter
    let (shorter, longer) = if a.len() > b.len() {
        (b, a)
    }  else {
        (a, b)
    };

    // fill the set with the characters from the shorter string
    let set: HashSet<char> = shorter.chars().collect();

    longer.chars().any(|c| set.contains(&c))
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let str1 = "abcdef";
    let str2 = "the quick brown fox";
    let str3 = "hijk";

    assert!(share_char(str1, str2));
    assert!(!share_char(str1, str3));
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=76567b94d3bd15b37e33acb9a8d701d5

Edit: changed to use collect

Edit2: I want to explain why I did the shorter/longer check and why I didn't just build two sets.

Inserting to a `HashSet` is a more expensive operation than just iterating over a string's characters. This means that there is a difference between building the set from the long string vs from the short one. Odds are that this difference is negligible as your strings are likely to be of similar lengths.

This expense difference is also why I don't build a second set. Not only do we save that insertion cost, we can also save some iterations since our `any` will short-circuit if it finds a match.

Edit3: Another thing. If you just want to check whether a string contains any of a given set of characters, you should use pattern matching.

```
str1.chars().any(|c| match c {
    'a' | 'd' | 'f' | 'e' => true,
    _ => false,
});
```

This will be much more performant than even using a static Set.

Answer (score 2):

`.any + .contains` means iterate **all** elements from one string for **each** char from another one (complexity `O(nm)`);

---

Instead, you can use hashmap and store every **char** as key and **bool** or **int** as value:
in this case you store all chars from first string in first iteration and then iterate second string, trying to get each char from hashmap.
If char exists, then return `true` immediately (complexity in worst case `O(n+m)`).

---

For performance I recommend using array instead of HashMap when possible present keys as indices.

```
fn common_chars(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> bool {
   const ALPHABET_LEN: usize = 26;
   const CHAR_CODE: usize = 97; // a-97, z-122
   let mut alpahbet = [0; ALPHABET_LEN]; 
   for c in s1.chars() {
      alpahbet[c as usize - CHAR_CODE] += 1; // store each char from first string
   }
   for c in s2.chars() {
      if alpahbet[c as usize - CHAR_CODE] != 0 { // a stored char is found!
         return true;
      }
   }
   false
}
#[test]
fn test() {
   let str1 = "abcdef";
   let str2 = "the quick brown fox";
   let str3 = "hijk";
   assert!(common_chars(str1, str2));
   assert!(!common_chars(str1, str3));
}
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide explanations on how it works, why is it more efficient ?